# How to code optional attribute without value to show/hide some blocks?

Tags: html, angularjs

How to code optional attribute without value to show/hide some blocks?

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKSsem2HgGJzNmFKFmad?p=preview)

For example, when the "showsum" attribute exists in the line below:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" showsum headers="['Table Header 1', 'Table Header 2']">
```

I want to show this line (ex: Sum: 12)

```
<td ng-show="showsum">Sum: {{ getCol1Sum() }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well since the `ng-show` directive takes in an expression, you cannot use it the way you did there,

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.

i dont know what your reason is to define it as an attribute, but what you can do is create a directive

like so

```
myApp.directive('showsum ', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A', // restrict to an attribute so we can use it as such
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.showsum = true; // set the show sum expression so we can access it in the scope 
       }
   }
})
```

example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mE5LrSMWdIwPRazEdD3b?p=preview

it will create a showsum attribute for the scope and you can do w.e you want with it